# How to change value of nested properties in a JObject?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a config.json that looks like this:

```
{
  "Field": {
    "FieldKey1": "FieldValue1",
    "FieldKey2": "FieldValue2"
  },
  "List": [
    "ListEntry1",
    "ListEntry2"
  ],
  "UnnestedKey": "UnnestedValue"
}
```

I can read access nested values the following way:

```
var x = await ConfigUtils.Get(configPath, "Field.FieldKey1");
Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
```

with:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static async Task<JToken> Get(string filePath, string key)
{
    JObject jObject = await GetJObject(filePath);
    
    return jObject.SelectToken(key)
           ?? throw new KeyNotFoundException($"Key \"{key}\" doesn't exist in {filePath}.");
}
    
private static async Task<JObject> GetJObject(string filePath)
{
    string jsonString = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(filePath);
    
    JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
    
    return jObject;
}
```

which correctly prints "FieldValue1".

However, I can't figure out how to *change* a nested value in the config.json.
If I try:

```
await ConfigUtils.UpdateValue(configPath, "Field.FieldKey1", "NewValue");
```

with:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static async Task UpdateValue(string filePath, string key, string value)
{
    JObject jObject = await GetJObject(filePath);

    jObject.AddOrReplace(key, value);

    await WriteJObject(jObject, filePath);
}
```

a new unnested key called `Field.FieldKey1` ist added instead of changing the value of `FieldKey1` inside `Field`.

How do I have to modify my UpdateValue method to work for nested values?
I know I probably have to use `jObject.SelectToken(key)` like in my Get method, but I can't figure out how to go from there and am hopelessly confused regarding JToken, JProperty, JObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Replace` on the found token and `JToken.FromObject` to create a new value:

```cs
var js = """
{
  "Field": {
    "FieldKey1": "FieldValue1",
    "FieldKey2": "FieldValue2"
  },
  "List": [
    "ListEntry1",
    "ListEntry2"
  ],
  "UnnestedKey": "UnnestedValue"
}
""";

var jObject = JObject.Parse(js);
var selectToken = jObject.SelectToken("Field.FieldKey1");
selectToken.Replace(JToken.FromObject("NewValue"));

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jObject)); // {"Field":{"FieldKey1":"NewValue","FieldKey2":"FieldValue2"},"List":["ListEntry1","ListEntry2"],"UnnestedKey":"UnnestedValue"}
```

Answer (score 0):

To update a nested value in the config.json, you need to use the SelectToken method to get the JToken representing the nested value, and then update the value of that JToken.

```
public static async Task UpdateValue(string filePath, string key, string value)
{
    JObject jObject = await GetJObject(filePath);

    JToken token = jObject.SelectToken(key);
    JProperty property = (JProperty)token;
    property.Value = value;
    
    await WriteJObject(jObject, filePath);
}
```